# Page visibility API in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, events

When using the page visibility API in Google Chrome the event is fired twice.
This is some thing that happen only in Chrome.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
    if (!document.hidden) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

By what I know of the API the event is suppose to fire once.
I am trying to fire it once regardless the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in Chrome:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409467

The workaround seems to be to attach to the window:

> Workaround: use window to attach the event to. This seems
>   non-standard.

Comment: Attaching the event to window not triggering the event at all.
`code`window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
    if (!document.hidden) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});`code`

Answer (score 3):

You have to do two different methods to detect `browser window` and `browser tab`.

For a cross-browser solution check out this example:

**[Using HTML5 Visibility API to manage the focus of browser tabs and windows](http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/sxgJl)**:

For detecting if the `browser tab` is active or not, use the [HTML5 Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API):

```
/////////////////////////////////////////
// main visibility API function 
// check if current tab is active or not
var vis = (function(){
    var stateKey, 
        eventKey, 
        keys = {
            hidden: "visibilitychange",
            webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
            mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
            msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
       };
  for (stateKey in keys) {
      if (stateKey in document) {
        eventKey = keys[stateKey];
        break;
      }
  }
  return function(c) {
    if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
    return !document[stateKey];
  }
})();

/////////////////////////////////////////
// check if current tab is active or not
vis(function(){

  if(vis()){    

       // the setTimeout() is used due to a delay 
       // before the tab gains focus again, very important!
       setTimeout(function(){ 

          // browser tab gains focus
          // code goes here

       },300);      

   } else {

       // browser tab gains focus
       // code goes here    
   }
});
```

For detecting the `browser window` you just check the window `blur`, `focus`, `focusin`, and `focusout` depending on what browser it is:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////
// check if browser window has focus        
var notIE = (document.documentMode === undefined),
    isChromium = window.chrome;

if (notIE && !isChromium) {

    // checks for Firefox and other  NON IE Chrome versions
    $(window).on("focusin", function () { 

        setTimeout(function(){      

            // browser window gains focus
            // code goes here

        },300);

    }).on("focusout", function () {

        // browser window loses focus
        // code goes here

    });

} else {

    // checks for IE and Chromium versions
    if (window.addEventListener) {

        // bind focus event
        window.addEventListener("focus", function (event) {

            // the timeout is due to a slight delay when a browser tab regains focus
            setTimeout(function(){                 

                 // browser window gains focus
                 // code goes here

            },300);

        }, false);

        // bind blur event
        window.addEventListener("blur", function (event) {

            // browser window loses focus
            // code goes

        }, false);

    } else {

        // bind focus event
        window.attachEvent("focus", function (event) {

            // the timeout is due to a slight delay when a browser tab regains focus
            setTimeout(function(){                 

                 // browser window gains focus
                 // code goes here

            },300);

        });

        // bind focus event
        window.attachEvent("blur", function (event) {

            // browser window loses focus
            // code goes here

        });
    }
}
```

**Resources:**

- [MDN - visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange)
- [MDN - Using_the_Page_Visibility_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)
- Working example of the above code: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/sxgJl

I also converted this into a jQuery plugin if needed. You can download it on the GreenSock GSAP Forum, at this [link here](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/9059-cross-browser-to-detect-tab-or-window-is-active-so-animations-stay-in-sync-using-html5-visibility-api/#entry36347).

Or download the [TabWindowVisibilityManager jQuery Plugin](http://greensock.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=1622) directly.

I hope you find this helpful!